# Bulk inserting a file that has rows with less columns than expected by the format file

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, csv, bulkinsert

I have a file I'm using as a source to bulk insert into a table. However, the last 4 rows of the file has some bad data that causes the `BULK INSERT` query to crash with this error and result in no rows being inserted into the table.

> Msg 50000, Level 11, State 1, Procedure SQLErrorHandler, Line 79
>   ALREADYLOGGEDError 7330, Level 16, State 2, Procedure Bulk Insert ADS File, Line 1, Message: Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

I've determined that the reason why this error is occurring is that the format file expects a certain number of columns but the last 4 rows is construed to have only have one column each as they have no delimiters in them.

My question: is there a way to either skip over these rows or insert these rows with nulls in the other columns? Manual removal of these rows from the file is not an option.

Edit: I've tried the `MAXERRORS` option as others have suggested, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You can specify a `LASTROW` ordinal so that no attempt is made to parse the remaining records.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the MAXERRORS option for Bulk INSERT.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried setting the MAXERRORS option to a number well above the number of rows in the file, but the query still failed with the same option.

Comment: If you know the number of rows, you can use the LASTROW option.  I would also consider writing a program or script outside of SQL, like powershell, to cleanup the bad rows before doing BULK INSERT.